# Saving a dataset as XML can I override tag names produced to get smaller XML

Tags: c#, .net, xml, dataset

So I'm saving out a dataset to an xml file in an application where producing a smaller file is important.  Right now it just saves the XML elements as the name of the datasets tables and fields.  I'm wondering if instead there's a way to easily save out these tags as something other than the default dataset names and load them back in using the same names.

For example right now I'll do something like this to save out the dataset

```
XmlTextWriter xml = new XmlTextWriter("myfile.xml", Encoding.UTF8) { Formatting = Formatting.None };
myDataset.WriteXml(xml);
```

and it'll produce long xml that looks like this...

```
<MYDataSet xmlns="http://tempuri.org/MYDataSet.xsd">
<MyElement><ReallyLongTagNames>other info and tags</ReallyLongTagNames></MyElement>
...
</MyDataSet>
```

I want to be able to save and load stuff that looks more like this to conserve space but I can't find a good way to do it.  Good meaning keeping my dataset from being cryptic but still being able to load and save out XML like this.

```
<MYDataSet xmlns="http://tempuri.org/MYDataSet.xsd">
<a><b>other info and tags</b></a>
...
</MyDataSet>
```

Is there a good way to get xml to print out this way when saving off a dataset?

Comment: Are you wanting to be able to read the xml file after saving it off or are you just using this for transport / storing of data?

Comment: Yes, I'd like to be able to read back in the data after storing it.

Answer (score 0):

How about renaming the columns in the DataSet before exporting to XML?

Comment: I think this might be the best/only real way to do this.  Seems like it might be somewhat tedious and error prone especially with reading the data back in.  Is there an easy way to rename the columns that I'm missing?  Then read the xml back into the original dataset?

Answer (score 0):

If file size is important then use the Binary Formatter.  This will reduce the size dramatically.

```
            string path = @"D:\myfile.dat";
            BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
            mydataset.RemotingFormat = SerializationFormat.Binary;                
            using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(path))
            {
                bf.Serialize(sw.BaseStream, mydataset);
            }
```

Comment: This does drastically reduce the file size but isn't what I'm looking for.  I want to keep the format in XML.

Comment: Is there a reason for this? Do you want to be able to read the data outside the application?

Comment: I'm putting a dataset on a windows mobile barcode/rfid scanner with no network connectivity.  I may need to be able to place a fairly large amount of data on the scanner for it to be able to keep track of all the inventory needed in the application.  The scanners don't have a large amount of memory.  I'm experimenting with what's better to work with a sql server ce file or an xml file.  I've noticed the xml file I"m producing from my dataset is 80+% markup and not much bigger than the sqlce file

Comment: Are you reading the data back in to the app via xmldocument / xmlreader or serializing it back into memory?  If you are serializing it back into memory to read then use the binary to deserialize it back.  It's much quicker and definitely smaller.